# Mean squared displacement of a particle on a biased random walk

Tags: biophysics, statistics, diffusion, stochastic-processes

Given a particle on a 1-D random walk with some drift velocity $\nu_d = \frac{\Delta x_d}{\Delta t}$, the position in at some time step j is given by $$x_j=x_{j-1}+k_j L + \Delta x_d$$ where $L$ is the step length and $k_j \in \{-1,+1\}$ with equal probability. I tried calculating the mean square displacement using
$$\langle x_N^2 \rangle = \langle (x_{N-1} + k_N L + \Delta x_d)^2 \rangle = \langle x_{N-1}^2 \rangle + 2\Delta x_d \langle x_{N-1} \rangle + L^2 + \Delta x_d^2$$
Solving this recurrence gives that the mean squared displacement is exponential with respect to time, although intuitively, and when I graph it, it should be quadratic with respect to time. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happened to the $L^2 \langle k_N^2 \rangle$ term?

Comment: @DanielSank the $L^2 \langle k_N^2 \rangle$ term simplifies to $L^2$ since $k_N$ is either -1 or 1, and the terms with just a term of $\langle k_N^1 \rangle $ vanish since the mean of k is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to transform into coordinates that comove with the drift, i.e.
$$\tilde x_j = x_j + \Delta x_d j.$$
In those coordinates $\tilde x_j$, the problem reduces to a standard (fixed-step) random walk.

Nevertheless, your approach is also fine. You likely made an error when solving the recurrence relation. Note that the recurrence relation consists of two equations,
$$\langle x_j\rangle = \langle x_{j-1}\rangle + \Delta x_d,$$
$$\langle x_j^2 \rangle = \langle x_{j-1}^2 \rangle + 2\Delta x_d \langle x_{j-1} \rangle + L^2 + \Delta x_d^2.$$

Comment: Ah, I did make a mistake solving the recurrence relation, I treated the mean term as a mean squared term. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

### Answer

With initial condition at the origin $x_0 = 0$, and independent $k_i$s, the mean squared displacement at step $n$ reads
\begin{equation}
  E\{x_n^2\} = n^2 \Delta x_d^2 + n L^2 \ .
\end{equation}

### Details

Using the recurrence relation
\begin{equation}
  x_n = x_{n-1} + L k_n + \Delta x_d
\end{equation}
you can easily write the position $x_n$ as a function of the initial position $x_0$, the random variables $k_i$, $i=1:n$, and drift $\Delta x_d$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  x_n & = x_{n-1} + L k_n + \Delta x_d = \\
 & = x_{n-2} + L k_{n-1} + \Delta x_d + L k_n + \Delta x_d = \dots = \\
 & = x_0 + L \sum_{i=1}^n k_i + n \Delta x_d \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
that is possible to write using vector formalism as
\begin{equation}
  x_n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &\underline{L}^T & n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ \underline{k} \\ \Delta x_d\end{bmatrix} \ .
\end{equation}
Using this formalism, it's quite easy to evaluate the mean squared displacement as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 E\{x_n^2\} & = E\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 &\underline{L}^T & n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ \underline{k} \\ \Delta x_d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_0 & \underline{k}^T & \Delta x_d \end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \underline{L} \\ n \end{bmatrix}\right\} = \\
 & = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &\underline{L}^T & n \end{bmatrix}  E\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 
  x_0^2 & x_0\underline{k}^T & x_0 \Delta x_d \\
  x_0 \underline{k} & \underline{k}\underline{k}^T & \underline{k} \Delta x_d \\
  x_0 \Delta x_d & \Delta x_d \underline{k}^T & \Delta x_d^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}  \right\} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \underline{L} \\ n \end{bmatrix} \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now, assuming $x_0$, $\Delta x_d$ are deterministic, and the $k_i$s are independent, so that
\begin{equation}
  E\{\underline{k} \underline{k}^T\} = \text{diag}(1,1,\dots,1) \ ,
\end{equation}
since $E[k_i^2] = 1$, it's easy to find
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  E\{x_n^2\} & = x_0^2 + 2 n x_0 \Delta x_d + n^2 \Delta x_d^2 + n L^2 = \\
& = (x_0 + n \Delta x_d)^2 + n L^2 \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
With initial condition at the origin $x_0 = 0$, this simplifies to
\begin{equation}
  E\{x_n^2\} = n^2 \Delta x_d^2 + n L^2 \ .
\end{equation}
If you need the recurrence formula for the mean squared displacement, you can find it comparing $E\{x_n^2\}$ and $E\{x_{n-1}^2\}$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   E\{x_{n-1}^2\} & = (n-1)^2 \Delta x_d^2 + (n-1) L^2 = \\
  & = E\{x_n^2\} - (2n-1) \Delta x_d^2 - L^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}